# How to Active Resharper's tab on Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I installed **ReSharper** successfully
but, still ReSharper was not appeared on Visual Studio's tab.

I will be glad if you can help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [VS2019](https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2019/03/16/breaking-ide-changes-in-visual-studio-2019/), Microsoft groups all 3rd party extensions under the Extension Menu

[image: Extensions menu]

> In Visual Studio 2019 top level menus from extensions are moved to the
>   Extensions menu as submenus

With a 3rd party extension [Extensions in Main menu](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Evgeny.RestoreExtensions) you can move the entries back to main menu:

> Starting from Visual Studio 2019, all extensions previously located in
>   the Main menu were moved into the Extensions menu. This extension
>   allows choosing between the new and old behavior by bringing up
>   selected extensions into the Main menu.

[image]

Comment: Menu for extensions can be moved back to main menu by `Extensions in Main menu` extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Evgeny.RestoreExtensions

Comment: Hurray! Muscle memory is painful to change. Alt-R-U-N FTW!

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly installed it you will find the resharper extension by clicking the `Extensions` -> `ReSharper` menu item.

Comment: in VS2019 , Microsoft moved all [extension entries into a submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549402/1466046)